# function not Printing

Tags: function, if-statement, pointers, while-loop, segmentation-fault

Please I need help.
I am writing a program to count and print vowels and consonants using pointers and functions, My code compiles successfully but does not display results.

It displays either "Your text count:0 vowels and 0 consonants" or "Segmentation fault"

I can't figure out the problem.

```
 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1000

void voyelle(char *word)
{
 int i,n,cons=0,vowel=0;
 n=strlen(word);

 while(*word<n)
 {
if((*word>='a'&& *word<='z')||(*word>='A'&& *word<='Z'))
{
  if(*word=='a'|| *word=='A'|| *word=='e'||*word=='E'||*word=='i'||*word=='I'||*word=='o'||*word=='O'||*word=='u'||*word=='U')
{
  vowel++;
}
 else
 cons ++;
}

word++;

 }
 printf(" Your text count:%d vowels and %d consonnants",vowel,cons);
}
int main(void)
{
 char text[SIZE];
 printf("Input your text: ");
 fgets(text,SIZE,stdin);

 voyelle(text);

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iterator variable is off, instead of doing `while(*word < n)`, do `while(i < n)` and above the loop set `i = 0` and do `i++` in the loop.

Comment: I am grateful. after editing to a do-while loop as suggested It could only count the whole string as consonants.

Comment: Please is something wrong with my second if statement? if yes what should I do to correct it.